# Make route to correspond to slide within Bootstrap carousel and update that route when slide changes

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I am using ui-bootstrap and ui-router. I would like to have a URL structure that allows me to link to a slide within a carousel such as,

```
/carousel/123/slide/789
```

This would load carousel "123" and display slide "789" as the active slide.

I would also like this URL to be updated to reflect whatever slide is showing.

I have tried a few ways of updating the route and although it works as intended, it doesn't get the job done as there are cases where it won't logically work.

*I know having the controller know about the DOM and using JQuery like the example code below is not the Angular way but I don't think it matters for the problem I am trying to solve. **I have been asked to add routes to this app, not to implement best practices.*** If moving things to a directive or otherwise fixing it would help me solve the present problem, than yes by all means, I would like to to it, otherwise it has to be left for another day.

First thing I tried does not activate the route for the first page loaded:

In my controller,

```
jQuery($scope.data.carouselSelector).on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  var newRoute = $state.href($state.current, {photoId:currentPhoto.id});
  $location.path(newRoute);
}
```

In my config,

```
.run(['$urlRouter', function ($urlRouter) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e, newUrl, oldUrl) {

      e.preventDefault();

      // This doesn't work because newUrl and oldUrl are the same when the app fires up at a route
      if (newUrl !== oldUrl) {
        $urlRouter.sync();
      } else {
        console.log('SKIP SYNCING');
      }

    });
    $urlRouter.listen();
  }]);
```

The second thing I tried was adding a query parameter indicating syncing the route should be skipped as the change has already occurred.

In my controller,

```
jQuery($scope.data.carouselSelector).on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  var newRoute = $state.href($state.current, {photoId:currentPhoto.id});
  $location.path(newRoute + '?ok=1');
}
```

In my config,

```
.run(['$urlRouter', function ($urlRouter) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(e, newUrl, oldUrl) {

      e.preventDefault();

      // I also tried adding a query parameter when the slide changes after the carousel has been loaded. But there is no way of knowing why skipSync=1 is in the URL. A user could have bookmarked it or even just reloaded the poage for instances.
      if (newUrl.indexOf('skipSync=1') !== -1) {
        $urlRouter.sync();
      } else {
        console.log('SKIP SYNCING');
      }
    });
    $urlRouter.listen();
  }]);
```

To complicate things a bit more, the carousel is in a modal which I open like this -

In my config,

```
.state("search.photo-view", {
  url: "/photo/:photoId",
  onEnter: ['$state', '$modal', function($state, $modal) {
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "photo-fullscreen.html",
        controller: "PhotoFullscreenController"
      }).result.finally(function() {
        $state.go('^');
      });
    }]
  })
```

It seems to me if there was a way I could know from the config if the modal is aready open, I could just assume it contains a carousel and is already displaying the slide I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up keeping track in the config whether the modal associated with the route is already open and ignoring the route change if the modal exists. Note I set the variable to null when the closing of the modal triggers the promise's 'finally':

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router"]);
myApp.config(["$stateProvider", function($stateProvider) {

  var carouselModalInstance, personModalInstance;

  $stateProvider.state("home.photo-view", {
    url: "/photo/:photoId",
    onEnter: ['$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function($rootScope, $stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {

      if (!carouselModalInstance) {
        carouselModalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: "photo-fullscreen.html",
          controller: "PhotoFullscreenController"
        }).result.finally(function() {
          carouselModalInstance = null;
          $state.go('^');
        });
      }
      }]
    })
}]);
```

Elsewhere (in my controller), I update the route upon the event ui bootstrap emits when a slide in the carousel has completed it's slide:

```
jQuery($scope.data.carouselSelector).on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

    var currentPhoto = getSlideForIndex(getCurrentSlideIndex());

    if (currentPhoto) {
      onPhotoChanged(currentPhoto);

    }

    var newRoute = unescape($state.href($state.current, {photoId:currentPhoto.id}));
    $location.path(newRoute);

});
```